# Minimize the expression $|x-1|+|2x-1|+|3x-1|+\dotsb +|119x-1|$

Tags: functions

Find the value of $x$ so that $|x-1|+|2x-1|+|3x-1|+\dotsb +|119x-1|$ is minimum.
Based on my trial-and-error method in Desmos, I am getting $x=\frac{1}{118}$; how do I get the correct answer?

Comment: Mathematica gives me a value of $49$ at $x=\frac1{85}$.

Comment: It is $$x=\frac{1}{85}$$ and the minimum value is given by $$49$$

Comment: The minimum value of $49$ is attained for all $\frac{1}{85}\le x\le \frac{1}{84}$.

Comment: @Andrei: that is a different expression (and not just because the number of terms is different). Look again.

Comment: This is [2010 AMC 12 A 22](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2010_AMC_12A_Problems/Problem_22).

Comment: @TonyK The expression is different, but the answers provided there seem to offer techniques which will apply here, as well.  For example, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3013513/468350) seems to deal with the general case offered here.  A question need not be a *precise* duplicate in order to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At $x=\frac1n$ for an integer $n$ with $1\leq n\leq119$, the slope of $f$ increases by $2n$. For negative $x$, the slope is equal to $-1-2-\cdots-119=-7140$, and for $x>1$, the slope is $1+2+\cdots+119=7140$. We have to check for which $n$ the slope changes from negative to positive.

So we want to find the greatest $n$ such that $2\cdot119+2\cdot118+\cdots+2n\geq 7140$. The left-hand side is equal to
$$
\frac{(2\cdot119+2n)(120-n)}{2}=14280+n-n^2
$$
and now we can just solve:
$$
14280+n-n^2\geq 7140\\
n^2-n-7140\leq 0\\
n\leq85
$$
So at $n=85$ the direction of the slope changes, so $x=\frac1{85}$ gives the minimum. The fact that we actually get an exact integer solution to the inequality means we can also choose $n=84$, as between those two points the slope is actually horizontal.